# How to use Ruby Mechanize to automatically like Facebook posts

Tags: ruby, facebook, mechanize, bots

I'm trying create a bot which automatically "likes" Facebook posts. Using Mechanize I can log into facebook, but unforunately the links to the like button are not understood by Mechanize - they seem to be obsfuscated by JS. The only links I see are the basics such as:

```
 <Mechanize::Page::Link
 "Edit friends"
 "http://www.facebook.com/friends/?ref=tn">
 <Mechanize::Page::Link "Developers" "http://developers.facebook.com/?ref=pf">
 <Mechanize::Page::Link "Careers" "/careers/?ref=pf">
 <Mechanize::Page::Link "Terms" "/terms.php?ref=pf">
 <Mechanize::Page::Link "Find friends" "/find-friends/?ref=pf">
 <Mechanize::Page::Link "Privacy" "/policy.php?ref=pf">
 <Mechanize::Page::Link "Mobile" "/mobile?ref=pf">
 <Mechanize::Page::Link "Help Centre" "/help/?ref=pf">
```

Anyone have any idea how I could get Mechanize to see the "like" links?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not try hitting the mobile version of the site. http://m.facebook.com.  It looks like the Like links aren't using any JS there.

Comment: It worked. Nice lateral thinking! I would have hacked forever on the main site, where all it took was a visit to the mobile version. Good advice in general for screen scraping and bot difficulties.

Cheers